# I've just deleted important registries by mistake - can I somehow fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, restore

There was a game which was not working properly. I've found a fix online, but I've deleted the wrong dir. (yes, that was just dumb)

I had to delete this:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Uninstall > Origin (DELETE FOLDER)

And I deleted CurrentVersion. Now my PC won't boot up (it tries to repair itself but it can't - according to the logs it creates the error can't be found)

What are some options to deal with this?

Comment: There isn't a solution to this problem, you deleted a key, that should never be deleted.  There is a very small chance that a restore point might work, but even that might not work, due to the importance of the CurrentVersion key (you basically deleted the entire tree which is bad).

Comment: Windows does keep a registry backup. You can boot up the repair console and copy the backup registry files over the regular ones.

Answer (score 1):

Export it from a working copy of windows and import into this copy of windows.

1. Boot off the windows DVD/USB bootable
2. SHIFT F10
   or
   SHIFT F8
3. should get you a command prompt
4. regedit
5. Click HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and then load hive.
6. Find SYSTEM (registry file) normally located c:\windows\system32\config but in this environment it could have ANY drive letter.
7. Click Open
8. name it **x** for simpicity
9. Now you will have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\x
10. You need to do a search and replace on the file you exported
    Open in notepad

> ```
>  find [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
>  replace with [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\x
> ```

Save and import

reboot and test.

Comment: As far as I know, the windows cd key is stored in the CurrentVersion which I've just deleted, right?